# How to resolve environmental variables in read command like they are resolved when being passed as parameters to a script

Tags: bash, read

I have a script that can either be passed arguments at invocation, or display a prompt with instructions if none are passed. I can pass $FILE_LOC as an parameter and that gets expanded before being assigned as say $1, but if I use read command it stores a literal "$FILE_LOC".  Is there a nice way to expand input if it was entered as an environmental variable when using the read command?  I've seen tricks using eval but I'm hoping there is a cleaner built-in way.

ex both user input and parameter input being the same for input being /full/path/to/file, ./relative/path/to/file,  ~/home/path/to/file, $saved_path_to_file, ${saved_path_to_file}/subfolder  in something like:

```
if (( $# -eq 0 )); then
    read -p "Enter target file location:" file_loc
else
    file_loc="$1"
fi

echo "the full path is $(realpath "{$file_loc}")"
```

Comment: Why do you read the data interactively at all? Why not pass that information via the command line. That would 1) solve your problem, and 2) not be annoying for the user.  If the user provides no argument on the command line, output an error message (they used the script in the wrong way).

Comment: the additional issue here is that on the shell command line, `$foo` would be expanded regardless of it's exported in the environment, while the script would only see it if it is exported. I.e. just setting `foo=something`, running the script and having it expand `$foo` would not work. But `script "$foo"` would, making those two ways of passing the value confusingly different. Probably better not do that.

Comment: If you're considering looking at environment variables, just pick a name and look at the value of that (if set), so the user doesn't need to enter it. E.g. if the name is `FILE_LOC`, the user can run `export FILE_LOC=...` and then run the script. Programs that insist on asking for stuff interactively are a bit of nuisance, as they're hard to use in scripts, and on the command line, you can't edit all the values at the same time, like you can with command line args. Sure, you had the option of using the command line here, but it doesn't really make people love interactive entry.

Comment: @they there are 6-7 parameters being passed so it would be nice (and is a requested feature) to include some additional instructions for each of them rather than forcing the user to read a long help text.  I wasn't expecting it to be that hard to resolve this issue so I may have to reconsider